# Pandas Groupby Count with filter using adult data set

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a filter to my dataset to identify count of males grouped by education type.

The dataset I'm using can be found here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult

This is my code, it doesn't return a value.

```
maleCount = df[df.sex=="Male"].groupby(['education','sex'])['sex'].count()
```

[image]

I've tried using the .filter() command, but I don't know if it possible to use that in combination with .count()

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the counts for each 'education' type for the gender 'Male', you could simply do the following:

```
df[df.sex=="Male"]['education'].value_counts()
```

Please note there will be as many counts as the distinct counts for the variable 'education'.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
MaleCount = df[df.sex.str.contains('Male')].groupby(['education','sex'])['sex'].count()
```